# MSQM send serializable message with byte array property using binary formatter

Tags: c#, serialization, message-queue

I'm sending a MessageQueue message with a byte array property but I always get the following error:

Cannot deserialize the message passed as an argument. Cannot recognize the serialization format.
   at System.Messaging.BinaryMessageFormatter.Read(Message message)
   at System.Messaging.Message.get_Body()

Serializable message class:

```
[Serializable]
public class EmailMessage
{
    public string SenderEmailAddress { get; set; }

    public string Recipients { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public bool IsHtml { get; set; }

    public List<EmailMessageAttachment> Files { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class EmailMessageAttachment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

Send:

```
public static void QueueMailMessage(EmailMessage emailMessage)
    {
        var messageQueuePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NotificationServiceMsqmPath"];
        var emailMessageQueue = new MessageQueue(messageQueuePath, QueueAccessMode.Send)
        {
            Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter()
        };
        var message = new Message(emailMessage) {TimeToBeReceived = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)};

        emailMessageQueue.Send(message, MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
    }
```

Receive:

```
private static EmailMessage ReceiveQueueEmailMessage()
    {
        var emailMessageQueue = new MessageQueue(AppSettings.MessageQueuePath,
            QueueAccessMode.ReceiveAndAdmin)
        {
            Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter()
        };

        emailMessageQueue.MessageReadPropertyFilter.SetAll();

        var message = emailMessageQueue.Receive();
        var body = message?.Body;
        var emailMessage = (EmailMessage) body;

        if (emailMessage == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Email message cannot be null.");

        return emailMessage;
    }
```

When I try to use the xml serializer the byte array data is read as null.

Comment: You can't send a binary byte array in an html message.  There are invalid html characters in binary data.  So you must convert to a string : string data = Convert.ToBase64String(byte[]);

Comment: @jdweng please post comment as answer.